# Firefox is trying to communicate with Chrome in private browsing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Can someone kindly explain to me why when I fire up Firefox browser in private mode FF tries to interact with Chrome browser?  I opened up a private window in FF and after 20 minutes of inactivity, a dialog popped up saying that some kind of JS script is taking a long time.  This is without browsing any sites.  The options were "stop," "debug" and something else.  I clicked "Debug" and attached picture is what was shown. So the question is 1) what is this script for 2) FF is FF and Chrome is Chrome...how come they are passing each other love notes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with Google Chrome. Firefox calls the browser UI the "application chrome" or "browser chrome" (a term that predates Google Chrome's existence, and is now difficult to Google for). Examples of this usage:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Browser_chrome_tests
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Hiding_browser_chrome

> "There are times in which an extension may find it useful to hide **browser chrome (that is, toolbars, the location bar, and so forth)**..."

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz.  CIA is off the hook.  I will accept as an answer as soon as I can.